# What is the runtime of 2-4 tree deletion

Tags: java, analysis

Why is the best case run time for deletion from a 2-4 tree O(logn) and not O(1)?

Comment: Why don't you do prior research? Why do you drop questions here that awfully sound like "please do my homework"?

Comment: Why *would* it be O(1)? (I'm not saying you're crazy for thinking it might be. But if you want people to explain where your reasoning is going wrong, you should explain what your reasoning actually is!)

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way, if you delete from the root node of a 2-4 tree, then you will have to perform O(log n) swaps, as well as fuse and drop operations to satisfy the structural and ordering properties of a 2-4 tree. It's the same case if you deleted from a non-leaf node. Now, if you delete from a leaf node, it's still a O(log n) operation, since you have to traverse to the bottom of the 2-4 tree to delete from the leaf, which is an O(log n) operation.

Good luck studying for Prof. Zoom's exam :)

Comment: Your a smart cookie.